# Why python unittest fails to mock some static methods

Tags: python-3.6, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have some static methods written in util files. When I try to patch them and add a side_effect to return a specific value, they just execute the original method content. It is not getting mocked. Why is this happening? Is there any way to overcome this issue, rather than trying to mock the internal methods of that method?

I am trying to mock below method which is in date_utils.py file.

```
def get_sys_date_in_sap_format():
    today = datetime.now()
    date = today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    logger.info("Date: {}", date)
    return date
```

It is patched using below approach;

```
@patch("src.util.date_utils.get_sys_date_in_sap_format", side_effect=mock_sap_date)
```

This method is invoked inside the method which I am trying to test. Some help is really appreciated, as I am confused as why it is happening. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: It depends on how you import the module - you may have to change your patch string, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Answer (score 0):

@MrBean Bremen, it worked when I changed the import to b.my_method instead of a.my_method. I have always been wondering about this issue. Thank you so much.

```
@patch("src.sap.file_upload_service.get_sys_date_in_sap_format", return_value="11.10.2019")
```